# android: showing only part of page using webview

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to show only part of page in an WebView, eg. from 400th line to 600th line of html code.(that part contains data frame on webpage i want to show)

Is it possible? How?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can partially load the page using WebView. Instead, what you can do to achieve this objective is to load the web and then extract only the part you want. You can get the content of the remote url with URLConnection.
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html

After that, just convert the acquired data to string, preprocess it. After doing this, you can pass the preprocess string (html chunk that you want) to the WebView for display.